# Mapping data from two objects two one with automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

Hi I am using autommaper for data transfer from object and I have a case where I have to map from two objects to one.

This the data I get from the repositories:

```
IEnumerable<GetStudentClassmates_Result> students = UnitOfWork.Dashboard.GetStudentClassMates(studentId);
IEnumerable<GetStudentTeachers_Result> teachers = UnitOfWork.Dashboard.GetStudentTeachers(studentId);
```

This the object I need to map this to:

```
public class ParticipantsDTO
{
    public IEnumerable<GetStudentClassmates_Result> Students { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<GetStudentClassmates_Result> Teachers { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this with autommaper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably You can wrap you `IEnumerable<GetStudentClassmates_Result>` and `IEnumerable<GetStudentTeachers_Result>` in a `Tuple` and define your Map based off that `Tuple`. The mapping code will look like this.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Tuple<IEnumerable<GetStudentClassmates_Result>, IEnumerable<GetStudentTeachers_Result>>, ParticipantsDTO>();
```

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your example looks like they contain the same classes so it looks like they would not need mapping.

I would be expecting a `GetStudentClassmates_ResultDto` object.

Please correct me and I will update my answer.

This articles shows you exactly how to map collections:

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Lists-and-arrays

First you need to create the map ie:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<GetStudentClassmates_Result, GetStudentClassmates_ResultDto>();
```

Then map them ie:

```
IEnumerable<GetStudentClassmates_ResultDto> ienumerableDest = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<GetStudentClassmates_Result>, IEnumerable<GetStudentClassmates_ResultDto>>(students);
```